# Find unique elements in the unsorted array

Tags: java, arrays

So everyone knows there is a task for beginners, where you have a sorted array and you need to find the number of unique values. For example, if `int [] sorted = {0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2}`, the outcome is **3 unique values**. And I was thinking - what if I want to do the same with unsorted array. I know I can sort it and make my life easier - but still.

An example: `int [] numbers = {2, 7, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7}`. My first thoughts - I need to have 2 `for loops` to find all the instances of **2**, than **7** and so on. And that is where I have doubts.

As you can see **7** repeats, and I wonder how can I make sure I won't count it twice. To be more precise - I need some sort of a flag, to indicate I have previously counted that element, but I am not sure how to write it down.

How could I approach this? Not necessarily in code, maybe just a little hint how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the to add all the values to the [`Set<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) in just one iteration which ensures you by its definition, that the values will be distinct. Use the [`LinkedHashSet<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) to maintain the order. Otherwise, [`HashSet<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) will do the job as well.

```
new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(array)).toArray();
```

Alternatively, you can use the [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) feature that Java 8 newly offers you:

```
Arrays.stream(array).distinct().toArray();
```

Comment: thank you, @nikolas, appreciate this detailed answer

Answer (score 6):

you can use Set to get unique elements

```
int [] numbers = {2, 7, 3, 2, 3, 7, 7}

Set<Integer> uniqueValue = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

or even easier if using Java 8

```
Arrays.stream(number).distinct().toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of hashmap.
Key being the number and value being the count.
Update the count every time you find the key.
If key not available make an entry with value as 1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two `for` loops, you just need a `Set` containing the numbers you've encountered. Add to the set in a loop, and at the end, it contains the unique numbers found in the array.

Comment: You don't even need a counter: you could use a `Boolean`, where "true" indicates uniqueness, and "false" indicates non-uniqueness: `map.compute(k, (k, old) -> old == null);`.

Comment: @AndyTurner - LOL, timing! I just ninja'd saying use a `Set` instead of a `Map`. (I'd misread the question at first that it was to find how many times each number appeared, but it's just finding which numbers are in the array.) Don't even need a flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set`, which contains only **unique** values, so if you put all your array into a set, then you get the size of the set, it's done :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is by using an integer Set as explained in the other answers.

If you're looking for a solution without that, here is the alternative way:

If you want to use two for loops, to avoid duplication, you could "wipe out" all the instances of 2, and then 7, and so on every time you find it. 
For example overwriting all the 2's and 7's with a number like 0 would work if you:
1) ignore all 0's (so you don't count the overwritten duplicates)
2) check if there are any 0's in the array in the first place, so you don't ignore a 0 which was originally in the array, and counts as a unique number.

Hope this is enough to give you an idea of how it's done!